# URL error when invoking an aura:application

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, web

We have an aura:application that wraps an LWC component.

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
    <c:billingCalc recordId="{!v.recordId}"" />
</aura:application>
```

billingCalc is lightning web component (LWC).

We were able to invoke it using the URL "https://cmpdev01-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/NAMESPACE/BillingFinalizer.app?recordId=a0I3i0000002oUF" where NAMESPACE is the package namespace prefix.
This URL works fine in development (scratch orgs with namespace) and in the packaging org. But when we try to use it in an org where we have deployed the managed package, we get "URL no longer exists" error.

We have tried replacing "c:billingCalc" with "NAMESPACE:billingCalc" without any success.

Please let us know what we need to do to make this work

Comment: Turns out that I had to setup the app for global access. Added access="global" and the link is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Adding access="global" to the aura:application fixed the URL issue.